# Inserting array in params.put and get the data thru $_POST in PHP

Tags: php, android, arrays, web-services, android-volley

I'm trying to send an array to the webservice together with some other non-array information. I've tried many ways, I was able to get the other values of param but wasn't able to retrieve the array data successfully. Here is my code:

```
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Log.wtf("PID HERE", pid);
            params.put("pid", pid);
            params.put("election_id", election_id);
            params.put("count", String.valueOf(AppController.getInstance().getNum_positions_needed()));
            int i = 0;
            for(String object : email){
                name.add(object);
                params.put("email["+i+"]", object);
                Log.wtf("email["+i+"]", object);
                i++;
            }
            return params;
        }
```

And on the webservice, here is my code as well:

```
    $pid = $_POST['pid'];
    $election_id = $_POST['election_id'];
    $count = $_POST['count'];

    for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){
        $username = $_POST['email['.$i.']'];
        $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO nomination_result( username , pid , election_id) 
        VALUES ('$username', '$pid', '$election_id')");
    }
```

I am able to retrieve the data coming from the android side except for the array, in which I'm trying to retrieve through `$_POST['email['.$i.']']`.

Comment: Try `$_POST['email'][$i]`

Comment: WOW! I've been trying to find solutions on this issue for a couple of days already. Luckily I decided to ask! Thank you very much!  You solved it!